# yii2 Grid Filter - Ignore Filter Input Change

Tags: jquery, gridview, filter, yii2

I'm adding a range filter in yii2 gridView which when you click on the filter input, shows a popover like the one shown.

[image]

The div for the popover is inside the `td` filter cell (`position:absolute`).

When I change the I change the 'from' or 'to' value, it triggers the grid to reload and filter from `yii.gridView.js`. How can I avoid the grid filtering when I change these input values? Ie. stop the 'applyFilter' function from yii.gridView.js running?

The listener appears to be on inputs located within the filter row.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to bind a new click and 'enter press' listener to the 'from' and 'to' filter inputs, and then use the `bindFirst` to bind it before the `yii.gridView.js` and return false to stop it propagating. Like so:

```
/**
 * Need to bind first to stop yii.gridView.js triggering filter change   
 */
$filterInputs.bindFirst('change.yiiGridView keydown.yiiGridView', function() { 
    if (event.type === 'keydown') {
        // enter button
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $btn.trigger('click');
            return false;
        }
    } else return false;
});

/**
 * Bind to the front of the event listener queue
 */
$.fn.bindFirst = function(name, fn) {
  var elem, handlers, i, _len;
  this.bind(name, fn);
  for (i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
    elem = this[i];
    handlers = jQuery._data(elem).events[name.split('.')[0]];
    handlers.unshift(handlers.pop());
  }
};
```